# N-tier Entity Framework alternatives?

Tags: entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

We are about to build an externally facing ASP.NET MVC application, and the server team is requiring that we NOT connect directly to the database, but rather build a middle-tier application server and run all the requests through the middle tier service app. The middle-tier service app is (of course) allowed to connect to the SQL Server.

We had originally planned to create a REST API 2.0 Web service for the middle-tier application pushing JSON back and forth. However, we recently stumbled across the n-Tier Entity Framework (see links below) that pretty much exactly meet our needs, allowing us to develop our ASP.NET MVC application as if we were directly connected to the database, but it takes care of all the plumbing to remotely execute the EF queries and updates, even offering transaction / unit of work support for the updates. We pulled the packages down and were able to quickly construct a proof-of-concept within only 3 hours, and are quite excited about using it.

My question is this: I notice that although there are 33 releases, which is a good sign for stability, no new builds have been posted since 1.9 over two years ago. Are developers still actively using this library? Is there a newer technology or library that we should be considering? We really like the convenience of being able to code the client side directly with the LINQ queries returning fully populated graphs of data, and the updates being a simple one-line call wrapped in a transaction block. We don't want to have to create a full middle-tier API Service from scratch if we don't have to, but we don't want to use a library if it isn't being supported any longer.

[n-Tier GitHub website](https://github.com/6bee/ntieref)

[Archived n-Tier Codeplex website](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ntieref)

Comment: Have a look at Trackable Entities instead, perhaps?

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the tip, I'm checking that one out now.